# When multiple cognitive radios transmit simultaneously

Tags: rf, radio, spectrum, sdr

Cognitive radio nodes sense the spectrum and start their transmission opportunistically when the spectrum is found to be vacant. The question arises what if two or more nodes find the spectrum to be free and try to transmit through the same frequency channel simultaneously. Should the cognitive radio be equipped with additional intelligence in the form of an algorithm or similar to prevent this or is the sensing mechanism itself designed to avoid simultaneous transmission? How this is avoided at the physical layer?

Comment: This is not specifically a problem of cognitive radios so, why don't you look up what non-cognitive radios do to cope with transmit collisions. In other words, Cognitive radio is a red-herring.

Comment: @Andyaka I asked this in the context of cognitive radio sensing and opportunistic spectrum access. Isn't it different from traditional licensed radio which can transmit in its allocated band at any time without the need of sensing the spectrum?

Comment: Adding only a random "quiet time" before emitting and sensing again ?

Comment: @AdnanAli there are many bands (mainly unlicensed) where there can be multiple systems sharing that same limited spectrum hoping to get access to it and, they could pre-sense and transmit thus, the problem is not specifically anything to do with cognitive radios.

Comment: @Antonio51 Thank you. Yes, I think quite time before transmitting managed using a back off timer should work.

Comment: @Andyaka ISM (Industrial, Scientific and Medical) bands are unlicensed. IEEE 802.11 operates in this band and uses CSMA/CA for collision avoidance. However, it is not suitable for cognitive radio, which is the reason the cognitive radio standard IEEE 802.22 did not adopt it for use.

Comment: @AdnanAli   Be aware that "same" receiver "topology" and "programming" can lead to same "random" numbers. You need perhaps to read a "random" analog voltage. I remember a arduino program to do so ... but don't remember where ...

Comment: @AdnanAli You do not understanding my point. The problem of collision avoidance is not specific to cognitive radios hence, whatever measures are taken for non-cognitive radios can be used for cognitive radios. You seem to be ignoring the fact that decent mechanisms exist for non-cognitive radio systems that can equally apply to cognitive radios so, your question being specific to CR misses the bigger picture and underpins a lack of research on the subject.

Comment: @AdnanAli something as this, sorry it is in french, use google translate ... https://www.carnetdumaker.net/articles/generer-des-nombres-pseudo-aleatoires-avec-une-carte-arduino-genuino/

Comment: The ALOHA system was designed exactly for that. Still in use in some variants. The radio system is just part of the family of collision sensing media access protocols. Of course you could also use timeslots (like bluetooth last time I checked). Really *lots* of literature on the subject